# Django + exec() не изменяет значение переменной

Tags: python, django, exec

Есть вот такая вьюха

```
def product_list(request,category_slug=None,subcategory_slug=None):
category=None

products=Product.objects.filter(available=True)
sex=request.GET.get('sex',None)
metall=request.GET.get('metall',None)
price_range = request.GET.get('price_range', None)

filters={'sex':sex,'metall':metall,'price_range':price_range}
filters_for_model = {'gender': sex, 'metall': metall}
if price_range:
    min_price,max_price=price_range.split('-')
    filters_for_model = {'gender': sex, 'metall': metall, 'price__range': [min_price,max_price]}
if subcategory_slug:
    subcategory=get_object_or_404(SubCategory,slug=subcategory_slug)
    products = Product.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory)
    for key,value in filters_for_model.items():
        if value is not None:
            exec("products=products.filter({0}={1})".format(key,'filters_for_model[key]'))
```

Суть в следующем, в нее передаются фильтры GET запросом вида http://192.168.1.100/kolca-zolotye/?sex=man
Я фильтры я вытягиваю и помещаю в словарь filters_for_model = {'gender': sex, 'metall': metall}
Далее в цикле я выбираю продукты, по переданной категории и если фильтр не пустой применяю его, тут загвоздка в чем что написать вот так

```
for key,value in filter_for_models.items():
    products=products.filter(key=value)
```

Не катит т.к должно быть вместо key (gender,metall и т.п)
вышел я из ситуации хитрым образом
    exec("products=products.filter({0}={1})".format(key,'filters_for_model[key]'),locals())

Но в итоге я получаю не отфильрованные данные, т.к exec() почему то не меняет мою переменную products созданную до цикла, если в exec() поменять products на products1 например, то если сделать return HttpResponse(products1) - пишет что такой переменной нет. Если запускать из шелла то там работает и меняет переменную, уже пару дней ковыряюсь не пойму в чем загвоздка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
products = products.filter(**filters_for_model)
```

Comment: А что так можно было)) Спасибо, пересобрал словарь удалив None filters_for_model={key:value for key,value in filters_for_model.items() if value is not None}. И с вашим способом заработало)